# Best practice with Front-End dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, rest, frontend

I have a Front-End application with dynamic tables with differents sizes depending on data received by a REST request to my server. I am looking for a good way to handle the creation of theses tables.

First a table is created in html :

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="myid"></tbody>
</table>
```

And then I use the body of this table to dynamically create new lines of my table with css attributes, cells, text with differents styles etc...

There I found complicated to code with javascript since it is obviously easy to create a human interface in HTML, it becomes unreadable and hard to test in javascript.

At the beginning somene like this was done :

```
forloop on each rows{
    html += '<table><tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td></tr>';
    html += '<tr id="myid-' + i + '">';
    more and more unreadables lines then finally
    $('#myid').html(html);
}
```

This is obviously not a good solution since it's unreadable, the good thing is that I can control every css parameter, styles and events.

Then I have done something like this :

```
forloop on each rows{
    var newLine = document.getElementById("myid").insertRow(-1);
    newLine.id = "myid-" + i;
    newLine.setAttribute("style", "width: 10%; text-decoration:none;");
    newLine.onclick = function() {Expand(i);}
    etc...
}
```

But it is also hard to find how to control css parameters etc...

Then I have done an hybrid solution with a mix of the first and the second.

Does anyone has a good practice to handle dynamic tables ?
I was wondering if I could create an HTML files with blanks for id and text in span for example and fill when I call it from a javascript with parameters or any solution like this

**EDIT 1**
I am currently trying to install node package Handlebars, updates soon